# My code is getting array out of bounds exception in my code but it will run and crash after the first 2 inputs whats wrong

Tags: java, arrays, do-while, restriction

```
do {
     if (counter%2==0 && HP1[choice2] <= 0) {
       System.out.println("You cannot switch to that pokemon it has already fainted, choose someone else");
       choice2 = reader.nextInt();      
     } 
     else if (counter%2==0 && choice2 == index1) {
       System.out.println(myParty[index1] + " is already in battle. Please select a different pokemon.");
       choice2 = reader.nextInt();
     }
} while (counter%2==0 && HP1[choice2] <= 0 || counter%2==0 && choice2 == index1);
```

this is the code that is messing with my whole project I'm using it to restrict certain actions but it is crashing my whole game can anyone tell me what is wrong. The program will run but crash after the second user input where it shows exception

Comment: It would be helpful to post more information - like the exception you're getting, more information on how these variables are defined (ie. what type of data is HP?).  It's going to be tough to answer your question as-is.

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at PokeBattle.main(PokeBattle.java:124)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)                                                                                                                                 These are the things it tells me when it crash

Comment: HP is an integer defining total health points of pokemon and choice 2 is me asking them which pokemon they would like to switch to

Comment: Would you consider posting your code as a gist?  https://gist.github.com/ I'm happy to take a look but its hard to tell whats going on without more context.  At least the one file would be good.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see a bit more context, in particular: Where does the value of `index1` come from? How is it changed?

A tip for debugging array out of bounds exceptions: before accessing the array, print the array size and the index that's about to be accessed. For example, in your code, before the first `if` statement, add:

```
System.out.println("HP1 array size: " + HP1.length);
System.out.println("About to access index: " + choice2);

System.out.println("myParty array size: " + myParty.length);
System.out.println("About to access index: " + index1);
```

This way, you can reduce your problem to something more specific (eg. why is `choice2` or `index1` a certain value).

It's also generally a good idea to check for index out of bounds before you access an array, especially when dealing with user input (as it appears you are doing with the `reader` object).

You could check for this as so

```
do {
     if (choice2 < 0 || choice2 > (HP1.length - 1) || index1 < 0 || index1 > (myParty.length - 1)) {
       // handle the error
     }
     else if (counter%2==0 && HP1[choice2] <= 0) {
       System.out.println("You cannot switch to that pokemon it has already fainted, choose someone else");
       choice2 = reader.nextInt();      
     } 
     else if (counter%2==0 && choice2 == index1) {
       System.out.println(myParty[index1] + " is already in battle. Please select a different pokemon.");
       choice2 = reader.nextInt();
     }
} while (counter%2==0 && HP1[choice2] <= 0 || counter%2==0 && choice2 == index1);
```